# Which has a higher dps - Lightning Blade or Darkmoon Blade?

Tags: dark-souls-3

With 60 faith, which does more damage on average, Lightning Blade or Darkmoon blade?

Comment: Edited title to be a factual question not an opinion one. (Which is better is an opinion question). But this may still receive downvotes for showing no effort to find the answer yourself. (You could have done some internet research about the items before asking here).

Comment: This is not opinion based.

Comment: Also I don't have darkmoon blade.

Comment: You don't need to *have* a Darkmoon Blade to [look at the wiki](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Darkmoon+Blade).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither of these will do more damage "on average" as they are both weapon enchantment miracles that raise your weapon by 50 damage in their respective elements and *not* actual weapons.

If you wondering which will be more effective to more enemies, it will likely be Lightning Blade, as that seems to be a more common weakness, but bear in mind that if [this spreadsheet of boss elemental weaknesses](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YeiGqxpmMEb-uXNpAcHkBflCoBWDC-eQoOBubr4POCY/htmlview) is anything to go by, most enemies will only be taking 1-5 more damage from Lightning than Magic anyways.

Since these are both just miracles, it would be best to *know* your specific enemy's weakness and then enchant your weapon accordingly.

Comment: The wiki you linked to above had this to say about comparing the two (see under "Notes"): "the only advantage over the easier to acquire Lightning Blade is if used against enemies with high lightning resistance, since Darkmoon Blade deals magic damage. Otherwise the two spells appear to be identical."

Comment: I can't check right now, but since split damage is generally worse, when using a weapon that already have magic or lightning damage wouldn't it be better to use the buff that matches your weapon? I also recall some weapons getting way more damage out of specific buffs (Lothric Greatsword being better with Blessed than Lightning Blade I think).